# Shed panel warped, but isn't anymore

Tags: wood, outdoor, shed

I had a shed delivered two weeks ago.

It has been stored up right for a week when I noticed that some panels were bent/warped. It's now being returned and collected this week. See picture.

However the panels have now gone back to their correct shape. Is this something I should be worried about?

Eg will the warp return? Should I still get a replacement?

[image: shed warped]

Comment: How thick are those slats? Was there something pushing on them? I don't see any large knots the quality of the materials looks normal, wood will deform especially when green and if it returned to the proper shape I don't see any issue (note I work in a lumber mill logs are cut and milled and sent to retailers in some cases in less than a week almost all wood fir, cedar , hemlock is green or wet when purchased unless kiln dried or hardwood).

Answer (score 1):

The panel's material,size and construction are not given. May be it is not properly seasoned wood, so could be defective when machine cut to size too soon and warped on drying as grain is not along length or had ridgalls inside. After some time it might improve with moisture change and aging, but there is no reason to keep panels of demonstrated poor quality in bending and twisting.

Comment: Thanks. This is the item. http://www.argos.co.uk/static/Product/partNumber/5037607.htm

Comment: The timber needs periodic re-treatment too! One may want to forget it all if seasoned and pre-treated.